# How to check a program that currently using connection?

Tags: networking

Is there a command/program to check what program/daemon that currently using network connection or downloading updates behind the scene? Everytime I boot Ubuntu, I can't use the internet for 4-10 minutes because some program downloading some updates. I have check my software update configuration, it already set to weekly.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your internet connection itself? Ordinarily, downloading updates would not interfere with an Internet connection being used for another purpose. It would likely slow things down considerably on a dial-up connection, but even then, *still* not to a halt (and downloading updates on a dial-up connection would ordinarily take longer than 4-10 minutes). Also, how do you know that updates are being downloaded? You said, "because some program downloading some updates" but what makes you think that's what's happening? (Please *edit your question* to provide all this info.)

Answer (score 1):

You can see currently active TCP connections with the command:

```
netstat --tcp -np
```

You might need to run this as root or use sudo in order to get information on the process using the TCP connection. Note that just because a process has a TCP connection open, does not mean that it is causing a problem for other network access.

- Greg